# creating shapefiles in R from large dataframes

Tags: r, shapefile, esri

I use the `shapefiles()` library in R to create a shapefile from a dataframe.

The dataframe contains about 300,000 rows. My ddtable contains just one attribute. The shapefile has ESRI Shape type 1 (points). Neither the dd nor the ddtable contain missing values.

I have run `convert.to.shapefile()` to create the shapefile, but the process is still not complete after 5 hours. When I look at the task manager, about 3.51 GB of memory is in use (out of 8 GB), and most of the time, only 37% of the CPU is used.

I use Windows7Enterprise and R 3.1.0.

I have previously used `shapefiles()` to create shapefiles of a road network with over 140,000 links, and the creation of the shapefile never took more than about 5 minutes.

Does anyone have an idea of what may be going wrong?

Comment: Where is your code? Why shapefile anyway, they are hopeless. Use rgdal and sp for this, basic standard tools

Comment: I have circumvented the problem by saving my tables as csv, and loading them directly as Delimited Text Layer in QGIS. That worked fine. I'll have a look at rgdal and sp, thanks for the hint.